# "think opposing counsel to be the personal enemies of their parents" — why "the"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

From *To Kill a Mockingbird*:

> I’ve heard that lawyers’ children, on seeing their parents in court in the heat of argument, get the wrong idea: they think opposing counsel to be **the** personal enemies of their parents, they suffer agonies, and are surprised to see them often go out arm-in-arm with their tormenters during the first recess.

I wonder why the author uses "the" in "the personal enemies." The enemies in court aren't the only enemies a person might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speaker is emphasising that children might think not only is the opposing lawyer **an** enemy but **the** greatest enemy of their parent (because a child is not used to a legal argument in court)

So using "the" strengthens the rhetorical power of the speaker's words. It is a subtle effect, but it is effective when applied by a skilled writer.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I omitted the article, the sentence would sound just as natural but lose that emphasis, right?

Comment: yes, That is how I would read it.  It is certainly better with "the".